# Condo Heating Question

Tags: thermostat, heating

I'm a new condo owner and I have realized my hot water baseboard heaters won't turn off. It's getting hotter where I'm living and when I put my thermostat (*old mercury Honeywell*) to the lowest setting, my heat still comes on.

I'm hoping my thermostat just needs to be replaced. I don't think any of the breakers in my unit control the thermostat power and am not sure how to disconnect it to have it replaced.

Any help would be truly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have your own boiler or do you share with other units. Your valves might be stuck and not closing or the thermostat might be malfunctioning.

Comment: I share a boiler with the building. Is there a way to see if the valves are stuck or would a professional need to take a look?

Comment: You should be able to get some information and help from your condo association. Old thermostats can get stuck in the open or closed position so that would be a good guess.

Comment: Not a bad idea to replace your old thermostat with an inexpensive one, and that will eliminate it as an option.

Comment: Contact your HOA to ensure to whom the responsibility belongs. You shouldn't act your own on the "shared" or "common" elements in a condo.

Comment: Have to agree with @JACK.     Without knowing more about your heating system, it's probably a stuck zone control valve or stuck thermostat.  Those old mercury based thermostats were pretty reliable, so I'm guessing a stuck zone control valve. Any competent service person could easily diagnose this by simply disconnecting the thermostat and see if the heat then turns off. \

Comment: Thank you both for the advice. I've reached out to the property manager and will look into replacing my thermostat.